# Adt, Adl command is not getting recognized by windows

Tags: air

I have installed Adobe AIR on windows operating system.
I have also downloaded the Adobe AIR SDK and set in the "Path" variable the AdobeAIR SDK bin folder.
Then I had created a sample HTML-based AIR application with the AIR SDK.
and then in order to test the application, I typed the command 
"adl applicationName-app.xml".
Then I got the following result:

'adl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. 
Similarly when I typed the command "adt", I got the result:

'adt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: Did you restart windows after changing the Path variable?

Comment: Yeah I had, but still the same result

Answer (score 1):

Happen to me once. What happen was, i was trying to download windows version, but i unknowingly downloaded linux version, hence adl and adt will never be executable.

You might want to re-download the whole sdk and make sure the file name is "adt.bat" and "adl.exe"

Answer (score 1):

Go to the bin folder of flash builder where all compiler files are resides like mxmlc and adl. Than write down adl and than give compiler arguments. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the set path command on the command line:

```
c:\>set path
```

If the correct path to the AIR SDK isn't listed, then you did not successfully set the path variable. 
See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-71994050128cca87097-8000.html#WS2d929364fa0b8137-78b25bdf12a498897d1-7fff