# Unable to use adt, adl command from Adobe Air SDK in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, air, path, adobe, adt

I am a complete beginner at this and I would really really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

I just installed Adobe AIR runtime and Adobe Air SDK in my Windows 7 64-bit.

As per instruction from 'Adobe Air for Dummies' and other various articles about installing the SDK, I set up Path to my `C:\airsdk\bin` through 'System Properties'.

A few that I used as reference:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-71994050128cca87097-8000.html#WS2d929364fa0b8137-78b25bdf12a498897d1-7fff
and
[Adt, Adl command is not getting recognized by windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359274/adt-adl-command-is-not-getting-recognized-by-windows)

When I typed `set path` at cmd, it listed all the paths and I can see `...; C:\airsdk\bin` clearly listed there.

However, when I typed `adt -version` at cmd to check, it gave out `'adt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` The same for if I just typed `adt` as per 'Adobe Air for Dummies'.

I have restarted my computer; 
made another airsdk folder somewhere else and linked path to this new airsdk's bin folder, 
created 'New System Variable' as per http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRVSMJFTx94&feature=relmfu (Variable name: airsdk, Variable Value: `C:\airsdk\bin\adl.exe`), 
make path directly to `C:\airsdk\bin\adt.bat` and `C:\airsdk\bin\adl.exe` in Environment Variables; nothing works. 
It is still `'adt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.

I am running out of things and ideas to try and I desperately need to use Adobe Air. So, please, if anyone has any idea that I can try, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

```
Variable name: airsdk, Variable Value: C:\airsdk\bin\adl.exe
```

Of course adt or adl won't be recognized, you named your variable "airsdk" :)  Try typing

```
airsdk -help
```

And that should bring up the help for adl.exe (because that's where you value points to).  the easiest way, however, I will list in a few simple and easy to follow steps:

```
  - Click start >  right-click Computer > Properties > Advanced system settings
  - In System Variables, scroll down to the one named "Path" and click "edit" 
  - bring your cursor to the end of the variable value (it should end with a ; ) 
  - Add the path to the bin folder of the Air SDK. ( in your case C:\airsdk\bin)
  - click ok, ok, then voila!  no need to even restart.
```

I do realize you first mentionned in your post that you tried something like this because that's what it says in 'Adobe for Dummies', but if you follow these exact steps, you should have no problems.

If that's not the case, leave a comment and I'll have another look.